# What is the point of onAccuracyChanged method when building a pedometer?

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I am building my pedometer and I wanted to know why it needs the onAccuracyChanged method. I am wondering because it requires absolutely no code within it. Just made me wonder why it has to be inside the class if it does absolutely nothing?

```
@Override
public void onAccuracyChanged(Sensor sensor, int accuracy) {


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because if you implement SensorEventListener you also have to declare the abstract methods it has. Which is

```
public abstract void onAccuracyChanged (Sensor sensor, int accuracy)
```

Called when the accuracy of the registered sensor has changed.
And,

```
public abstract void onSensorChanged (SensorEvent event)
```

Called when sensor values have changed. Otherwise you get complier errors. You might not need it, but it has to be declared to match the signature.

[Source](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/SensorEventListener.html#onAccuracyChanged(android.hardware.Sensor,%20int))